# Why function does not receive arguments?

Tags: perl, data-structures, slice

I have next code:

```
my $str =  '';
new( (split ',', $str )[0] )
```

Here I split my `$str` and asks exactly one element from result list

But when check incoming data at `@_` I see zero elements

**Why function does not receive arguments?**
I expect one element

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please provide code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Please give us a small, complete, runnable example that demonstrates the problem. We can't run this code as we don't have the `new()` subroutine.

Comment: @choroba: I fixed code. Problem occur when `$str` was empty

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that tests what you say in your question.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

sub new {
  say 'new() received ' . @_ . ' argument(s).';
  say "The first argument was '$_[0].'" if @_;
}

my $str = 'one,two,three';

new( (split ',', $str )[0] );
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
$ perl split_test
new() received 1 argument(s).
The first argument was 'one.'
```

This seems to be working as expected. So it seems likely that your problem lies in parts of the code that you haven't shared with us.

Comment: The issue was when `$str` is empty, when split returns empty list and when slicing empty list results empty list

Comment: @EugenKonkov: So I was right - the problem **was** in a piece of code that you didn't show us. The bit that sets (or, sometimes, fails to set) `$str`.

Comment: @EugenKonkov: Oh, that'll be because it's not really an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I found the answer.

Problem was because of special case when I slice empty list.

This special case is useful at `while` condition:

```perl
while ( ($home, $user) = (getpwent)[7,0] ) {
    printf "%-8s %s\n", $user, $home;
}
```

Here is [documentation for this](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Slices)

```perl
@a = ()[0,1];          # @a has no elements
@b = (@a)[0,1];        # @b has no elements
@c = (sub{}->())[0,1]; # @c has no elements
@d = ('a','b')[0,1];   # @d has two elements
@e = (@d)[0,1,8,9];    # @e has four elements
@f = (@d)[8,9];        # @f has two elements
```